# SQL exists 2 table

Tags: mysql

i have 2 table like this

student

```
|-----------------------|
| id  | name   | value  |
|-----------------------|
| F01 | Ruben  | 4      |
| F02 | Dani   | 2      |
| F03 | Mike   | 3      |
| F04 | John   | 4      |
|-----------------------|
```

tutor

```
|---------------------------------|
| id | code  | student_id | class |
|---------------------------------|
| 1  | S2244 | F01        | IF-B  |
| 2  | S3251 | F02        | IF-B  |
| 3  | S2244 | F03        | IF-A  |
| 4  | S2244 | F04        | IF-C  |
|---------------------------------|
```

note, tutor.code ( S2244 and S3251) is foreign key from another table, tutor.class ( IF-B, IF-A, IF-C ) is foreign key from another table too, tutor.student_id is foreign key from student table, how to make the two tables combined and produce a result as below?

```
|-------------------------------|
| id  | name   | value  | class |
|-------------------------------|
| F01 | Ruben  | 4      | IF-B  |
| F03 | Mike   | 3      | IF-A  |
| F04 | John   | 4      | IF-C  |
|-------------------------------|
```

I want to take all the columns in the student table and combine them with the "class" column in the tutor table.

I have tried it myself but can only display data from the student table, and the "class" column of the tutor table cannot appear, this is the query I made

```
select s.*
from students s
where exists (
    select 1 from tutor t where t.student_id = s.student_id and t.code = 'S2244'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use an inner join here:

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.name,
    s.value,
    t.class
FROM student s
INNER JOIN tutor t
    ON s.id = t.student_id
WHERE
    t.code = 'S2244';
```